# Is any api doc can tech me support ios7 gamepad now?

Tags: xcode4, ios7, gamepad, gamepad-api

I want upgrade my game to support gamepad for ios7. Now I can't find any useful infomation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I found the offical doc, here:
https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/GameController/Reference/GameController_RefColl/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013201

iOS7

```
retina only(old 3gs can't update to ios7)
need gamecontroller.framework(optional)
controller is optional (without controller can also play game)
controller is auto connect.
gamepad or extended gamepad
wireless or not
```

keys(extended gamepad):

```
leftShoulder
rightShoulder
dpad
buttonA
buttonB
buttonX
buttonY
leftThumbstick
rightThumbstick
leftTrigger
rightTrigger
```

keys(gamepad):

```
leftShoulder
rightShoulder
dpad
buttonA
buttonB
buttonX
buttonY
```

code:

```
GCController(static get controller)
GCControllerAxisInput
GCControllerButtonInput
GCControllerDirectionPad
GCControllerElement
GCExtendedGamepad
GCExtendedGamepadSnapshot
GCGamepad
GCGamepadSnapshot
```

http://goo.gl/Dr9j3y